# Add CSRF to locust post request to prevent django error - Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)

Tags: django, locust

How to add CSRF to the URL to test django from locust to prevent the error `Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)`?

Here is what I have tried:

```
@task
def some_task(self):
    response = self.client.get("api/test/")
    csrftoken = response.cookies['csrftoken']

    self.client.post(
        "api/test/",
        {"csrfmiddlewaretoken": csrftoken},
        headers={"X-CSRFToken": csrftoken},
        cookies={"csrftoken": csrftoken})
```

The error I get is

> KeyError: "name='csrftoken', domain=None, path=None"

Comment: Is that error server side or client side? Also, have you tried not manually setting your token and cookie? Locust's client is based on the Requests package which should handle cookies automatically by default.

Answer (score 1):

Try to debug your response.cookies because you could have the "csrftoken" inside a class, which was my case.

I was getting something like this when I printed on the console:

> print(response.cookies)
>
> `<RequestsCookieJar[Cookie(version=0, name='csrftoken', value='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'`

which it will result in a `KeyError: "name='csrftoken'` if I try to access it via `response.cookies['csrftoken']`

What you need to do to get this value is `response.cookies.get_dict()["csrftoken"]`. This way you will be able to get the artribute value from inside the RequestsCookieJar class.

Answer (score 0):

You can have this problem when [the CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE) is `True`.

I believe browsers are smart enough to ignore the `secure` setting when making  requests to `127.0.0.1` so you don't notice the issue during normal development, but Locust respects the cookie's `secure` setting and will not send the CSRF cookie to `http://127.0.0.1:8000`, for example.

I had the exact same error and using `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE=False` fixed it.  You may also want `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=False`.